# Finding rank of powers of a nilpotent map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $T: V \longrightarrow V$ is a nilpotent linear operator, and we have that
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{ker}(T))=6 \\
\operatorname{dim}\left(\operatorname{ker}\left(T^{4}\right)\right)=22 \\
\operatorname{dim}\left(\operatorname{ker}\left(T^{7}\right)\right)=36 \\
\operatorname{dim}\left(\operatorname{ker}\left(T^{10}\right)\right)=46 \\
\operatorname{dim}\left(\operatorname{ker}\left(T^{14}\right)\right)=56 \\
\operatorname{dim}\left(\operatorname{ker}\left(T^{17}\right)\right)=60 \\
\operatorname{dim}\left(\operatorname{ker}\left(T^{19}\right)\right)=61
\end{array}
$$
Please find a possible value for $\operatorname{dim}\left(\operatorname{Im}\left(T^{8}\right)\right)$

Can we say that $\dim V$ is going to be $61$? and how to get $\dim(\ker(T^8))$?

Comment: Consider the integer sequence
$
k_n =\dim(\ker(T^n))
$. What properties do you know that it has? List as many as you can, see whether they help you.

Comment: Note that $\dim(\ker(T^n))$ can be coded in LaTeX or MathJax as \dim(\ker(T^n)), so your more complicated way isn't needed. Also, if you want something like $\operatorname{din}(\operatorname{ken}(T^n)$ to be coded as \din(\ken(T^n)) and to occur many times in the same document, you can write \newcommand{\din}{\operatorname{din}} above the \begin{document} in LaTeX, or just in dollar signs at the top of the posting in MathJax as used here. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim:**$\;$If $T$ satisfies the specified conditions, then

- $\text{dim}(V)=61$.$\\[4pt]$

  $\text{dim}(\text{ker}(T^8))=40$.$\\[4pt]$

  $\text{dim}(\text{im}(T^8))=21$.

**Proof:**

Let $n$ be the least positive integer such that $T^n=0$.

Since $T^{19}\ne T^{17}$, we must have $n > 17$.

If $T^{18}=T^{17}$, then $T^{19}=T^{18}=T^{17}$, contradiction since $\text{dim}(\text{ker}(T^{17})) < \text{dim}(\text{ker}(T^{19}))$.

Then we must have $\text{dim}(\text{ker}(T^{18}))= 61$, hence $T^{18}=T^{19}$, so $n=18$.

From $T^{18}=0\;$and$\;\text{dim}(\text{ker}(T^{18}))= 61$,$\;$we get $\text{dim}(V)=61$.

Since $T$ is nilpotent and $\text{dim}(\text{ker}(T))= 6$, it follows that $T$ has a Jordan Canonical Form with exactly $6$ Jordan blocks, $B_1,...,B_6$ say, where each $B_i$ has size, say, $s_i{\times}s_i$.

Since $B_i$ is a Jordan block of a nilpotent matrix, it follows that $B_i$ is nilpotent of index $s_i$, hence for $1\le k\le s_i$ we have

- $\text{dim}(\text{im}(B_i^k))=s_i-k$.$\\[4pt]$

  $\text{dim}(\text{ker}(B_i^k))=k$.

Consequently, if $k$ is a positive integer such that $B_i^k\ne 0$, then

- $\text{dim}(\text{im}(B_i^{k+1}))=\text{dim}(\text{im}(B_i^k))-1$.$\\[4pt]$

  $\text{dim}(\text{ker}(B_i^{k+1}))=\text{dim}(\text{ker}(B_i^k))+1$.

For each positive integer $k$, let

- $x_k$ be the number of $B_1^k,...,B_6^k$ which are nonzero.$\\[4pt]$

  $z_k=\text{dim}(\text{ker}(T^k))$.

Then we have

- $6\ge x_1\ge\cdots\ge x_{18}=0$.$\\[4pt]$

  $z_{k+1}=z_k+x_k$, for all $k$.

Next we apply the above relations . . .

From $z_1=6$ and $z_4=22$, we get$\;22=z_4=z_1+x_1+x_2+x_3=6+x_1+x_2+x_3$,$\;$hence $x_1+x_2+x_3=16$.

Then since $6\ge x_1\ge x_2\ge x_3$, it follows that $4\le x_3\le 5$.

From $z_4=22$ and $z_7=36$, we get$\;36=z_7=z_4+x_4+x_5+x_6=22+x_4+x_5+x_6$,$\;$hence $x_4+x_5+x_6=14$.

Then since $4\le x_3\le 5$ and $x_3\ge x_4\ge x_5\ge x_6$, it follows that $x_6=4$.

From $z_7=36$ and $z_{10}=46$, we get$\;46=z_{10}=z_7+x_7+x_8+x_9=36+x_7+x_8+x_9$,$\;$hence $x_7+x_8+x_9=10$.

Then since $x_6=4$ and $x_6\ge x_7\ge x_8\ge x_9$, it follows that $x_7=4$.

Then $z_8=z_7+x_7=36+4=40$.

Therefore $\text{dim}(\text{ker}(T^8))=40$,$\;$hence$\;\text{dim}(\text{im}(T^8))=61-40=21$.